# Check class of object passed into Java generic

Tags: java, generics

I want to check the type of object (String, ArrayList, int) that was passed into a java generic. How can I do this?

Comment: You can't. These types are not available at runtime. That is called type erasure.

Comment: Can you show the code where you need this? You know you can call `getClass` on any object right?